# C struct in Python

Tags: python, c, struct, ctypes

There is a `libx.so` which export 2 functions, and a `struct`,

```
typedef struct Tag {
    int num;
    char *name;
}Tag;

Tag *create(int n, char *n)
{
    Tag *t = malloc(sizeof(Tag));
    t->num = n;
    t->name = n;
    return t;
}

void use(Tag *t)
{
    printf("%d, %s\n", t->num, t->name);
}
```

I want to call `create` in Python and then save the `Tag *res` returned by `create`, later I will call `use` and pass the `Tag *res` saved before to `use`, here is it (just to demonstrate):

```
>>>libx = ctypes.CDLL("./libx.so")
>>>res = libx.create(c_int(1), c_char_p("a"))
>>>libx.use(res)
```

The above code might be wrong, just to demonstrate what I want to do.

And my problem is that, how could I save the result returned by `create`? Because it returns a pointer to a user-defined `struct`, and I don't want to construct `struct Tag`'s counterpart in Python, would `c_void_p` do the trick?

**UPDATE**

From @David's answer, I still don't quite understand one thing:

> the pointer (`c_char_p("a")`) is only valid for the duration of the
>   call to `create`. As soon as create returns then that pointer is no
>   longer valid.

And I assign `c_char_p("a")` to `t->name` in `create`, when the call to `create` finishes, is `t->name` a dangling pointer? Because according to the quoted words, that pointer is no longer valid after `create`. Why `c_char_p("a")` is no longer valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C code that you present is simply not going to work. You need to be much more precise about which party allocates and is responsible for the heap memory.

In your current example you pass `c_char_p("a")` to the C code. However, the pointer to that ctypes memory is only valid for the duration of the call to `create`. As soon as `create` returns then that pointer is no longer valid. But you took a copy of the pointer inside `create`. Thus the subsequent call to `use` is liable to fail.

You are going to need to take a copy of the contents of that string and store it in the struct. If you do that then you can use `libx.create.restype = c_void_p` safely.

But if you want the memory you allocated to be deallocated you will have to provide a `destroy` function to match the `create` function. With these changes the C code would look like this:

```
Tag *create(int n, char *s)
{
    Tag *t = malloc(sizeof(Tag));
    t->num = n;
    t->name = strdup(s);
    return t;
}

void destroy(Tag *t)
{
    free(t->name);
    free(t);
}
```

The Python code would look like this:

```
libx = ctypes.CDLL("./libx.so")
libx.create.restype = c_void_p
res = libx.create(c_int(1), c_char_p("a"))
libx.use(res)
libx.destroy(res)
```

Comment: i just went stinky in my pants

Comment: Well, sir, there are 3 things I don't understand. 1, `the pointer to that ctypes memory is only valid for the duration of the call to create.` Why is that? I presume it's because after the call to `create`, `c_char_p("a")`'s ref-count goes to zero, so `"a"` is garbage-collected, right?   2, in your code, `res` is a `c_void_p` object, but `libx.use` takes a `Tag *` arg, can I just pass `res` directly to `libx.use` without any cast?   3, why should I explicitly `destroy(res)`?

Comment: 1. Because that's all that ctypes marshalling guarantees. 2. For the purpose of marshalling, a pointer is just a pointer. If you never dereference it, you don't need to know the structure of it. This is opaque pointer pattern. 3. How else are you going to deallocate the memory.

Comment: If your code works then that's just by chance. Heaps are like that. Memory that has been freed is often still accessible and valid. So you can get lucky, but the luck usually runs out at some point.

Comment: I accept your answers to 2,3. But I don't quite understand the `ctypes marshalling`, how does it explain 1? Do I presume wrong about it (garbage-collection theory)?

Comment: The memory that ctypes passes to your C functions is prepared for the purpose of each particular function call. It is not valid outside the scope of that function call. You can refer to that memory inside the function call. Referring to it outside results in undefined behaviour. Might work, might not. So, take a copy of the contents.

Comment: Basically the python GC can't know when your C code is done with the pointer so there's nothing to keep it alive.

Comment: Sorry, sir, to be honest, I still don't quite understand your answer to the `1` question, stupid me. :-)

Comment: OK. I'll keep trying. You pass `c_char_p("a")` to the C function. The ctypes code allocates some memory and copies in the zero terminated string "a" to that memory. Your C function runs and takes a copy of the pointer which is actually pointing to memory allocated by ctypes. Your C function returns and then the ctypes code releases its reference to the Python object created by `c_char_p("a")`. At this point nothing is referencing the Python object and it gets garbage collected. Now your C function has a pointer to memory that has been deallocated.

Comment: Now, it's pretty clear. So `ctypes` guarantees that `c_char_p("a")` will only endure until the call to `create()` finishes, right?

Comment: @Alcott That's correct. The reason that you sometimes get away with accessing deallocated data is that typical heap implementations don't return the memory to the OS immediately. They hang on to it in case they can reuse the memory without the expense of an OS call. Ultimately the Python GC is implemented on top of C malloc, i.e. a typical heap.

Comment: So it's a good behavior to `strdup` the `str` object passed into a C function from Python, right? But what if `create` has already been implemented not using `strdup`, and I can't get access to the source code and re-implement `create` using `strdup`, then there is no way to ensure the code to work correctly, isn't it?

Comment: You can export `strdup` and `free` from your DLL and then use `strdup` to make a C string whose lifetime you control.

Comment: Well, I mean the DLL is not written by myself, which means `create` cannot be altered. Is there any other way to make `create` and `use` safe in Python code?

Comment: @Alcott You'd want to write another DLL to wrap it up. But if you didn't write the `create` function, how do you know what it looks like? If it was well written it will already be using `strdup`. What does the documentation for `create` say, and is there a `delete` that matches the `create`?

Comment: If the DLL is written with the only intention to interact with C, not Python, then `create` without `strdup` will be safe, right?

Comment: It would be poor design though. I'd always expect a copy to be made. And without a `destroy` there would be leaks. Do you have any documentation for this DLL?

Comment: Without documentation, it's very hard to be sure what the rules are. I wouldn't like to say with 100% certainty what you need to do. I hope that my comments have been able to help you decide how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Python does reference counting. You'll have to use Py_INCREF() and friends for objects that are returned from "external" libraries.

UPDATE: I don't know about .so loading by python, maybe the method proposed by @David Hefferman does this automagically.

UPDATE2: delete me!

Comment: The question concerns ctypes which is a foreign function interface, akin to pinvoke if you know that. `Py_INCREF` is simply not pertinent.